# Проблема с package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

пытаюсь запустить код и компилятор выдает ошибку связанную с package: его не находит.

`package MyGraph;` // импорт пакета

Структура программы:

[image: структура программы]

Я пытался импортировать еще так -

```
package sample.MyGraph;
```

Но результат идентичен:
[image: Результат]

Программа точно работает, просто она была скомпилирована в Eclipse, я же хочу запустить в Idea.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему.
Спасибо!

Comment: поставьте файлы типа ".class" в папку  out.

Comment: Снести пакет myGraph, указать в остальных классах пакет "pachae sample"

Comment: @aleshka-batman не помогло. Переместил все файлы с расширением .class в папку out, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: @GenCloud  спасибо, сработало !